# Cloned-input issues in Ionic2

Tags: forms, input, ionic2

I'm using ionic2 to build an ios app, the issue that I have at the moment is when you focus any text input or textarea. This action creates a clone of the same element mimic a behaviour on iOS, the problem is that clone element is misplaced and the action looks sloppy and slow, I'm hiding the element at this moment but it would be nice to know if there is a way to disable this behavior.

Many thanks in advance.